# Minimum value from ";"-delimited list of values in each field in CSV file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a big CSV file in which, in some cells, there is more than one value. How can I change these cells so that they instead only contain the minimum value?

For example, given this input:

```
id,disease_1,disease_2
1001,2008;2009,2009;2010
```

Notes

1. The column/field separator is a comma, `,`
2. Values in each cell are separated by a semicolon, `;` and are sorted in ascending order.
3. I want to start my algorithm from column 2

Desired output:

```
id,disease_1,disease_2
1001,2008,2009
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a small program to actually go through all cells. So, maybe 10 lines of python, or some awk, or some perl, whatever language you're most proficient with – I bet you're proficient with *some* language, as this looks like you'll be dealing with that data programmatically later on, anyways.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you , I need unix commands since i have very big csv file (1500 column and 50000 rows)

Comment: that's not "very big" as a table, it's just that CSV would be the wrong storage method for data of this dimensionality. A unix command is neither especially performant (the contrary is true, usually!), nor does it solve your problem of taking the minimum. You'll have to write this yourself. Which scripting/programming languages do you prefer?

Comment: I prefer Python, or SQL

Comment: Are the semicolon separated entries always pre-sorted, as shown in your example? if so, that would make the solution much simpler

Comment: @steeldriver yes they are sorted.

Comment: Ref your new note 3, where you say you want to start from column 2. Are there actually going to be any semicolons in your `id` column 1?

Comment: Please accept answers to your many questions across the various StackExchange sites. You are starting to look very selfish, and I'm sure you wouldn't want that

Answer (score 4):

The following is a "`put` expression" for use with the `put` sub-command of [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`; a tool specifically for processing structured data) to calculate the mininmum value of the `;`-delimited values in each field which is not the `id` field.

```
for (key,value in mapexcept($*, "id")) {
    value !=~ ";" { continue }

    var minimum = "";

    for (i,number in splitnv(value, ";")) {
        minimum = min(minimum, number)
    }

    $[key] = minimum;
}
```

Here we iterate over the fields in each record, but skip the field if it is called `id`. We keep track of a minimum value for each field while iterating over the numbers resulting from splitting the field's value on semicolons. At the end of the loop, the field's value is overwritten by the found minimum value. Fields that do not contain `;` are skipped at the start of the loop.

You could run this using

```bash
mlr --csv put -e script file.csv
```

... where `script` is the name of the file holding the short script above, or you may spell it out on the command line, like so:

```bash
mlr --csv put 'for (k,v in mapexcept($*,"id")) { v !=~ ";" { continue } var m=""; for (i,n in splitnv(v,";")) { m=min(m,n) } $[k]=m; }' file.csv
```

The result, given the data in the question, ought to be

```
id,disease_1,disease_2
1001,2008,2009
```

---

With a recent version of Miller (release 6+), the code could be shortened *significantly* by using the new `sort()` and `get_values()` functions:

```bash
mlr --csv put 'for (k,v in mapexcept($*,"id")) { $[k] = sort(get_values(splitnv(v,";")))[1] }' file.csv
```

This picks out the value that sorts first in each field's `;`-delimited list of values.

(Thanks to [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) for making me aware of this neat rewrite.)

---

If the values are already sorted, then it becomes even simpler and more efficient:

```bash
mlr --csv put 'for (k,v in mapexcept($*,"id")) { $[k] = sub(v,";.*","") }' file.csv
```

This simply truncates each field at the first `;` character.

Comment: Thank you, i have tried it on small excel test file, it seems to delete cell values in case it has only one value. It works if and only if every cell contains more than one value.

Comment: @Solomon123 I will update ASAP, it's a simple fix. EDIT: Now fixed.

Comment: @steeldriver Ah, yes, with the newer variant of Miller. I will add this at the end. Thanks. I really should be using only the newer version from now on!

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you much appreciate your help, it works very efficiently

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, I saw it. I think it may be more efficient to truncate the field with `sub()` in that case, but your approach would obviously also work.

Answer (score 4):

You [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741102/minimum-value-from-delimited-list-of-values-in-each-field-in-csv-file#comment1407841_741102) that the semicolon-separated items are always in ascending order, so the first one of each group is the minimum valued item that you want. On this basis you can simply strip the remaining values:

```
sed 's/;[^,]*//g' {file}
```

Note that this presupposes your data is a simple CSV format and does not use quoted text strings that also contain semicolons and commas. If that is the case this text-based solution cannot work and you will have to use a more complete solution such as an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/741105/100397) using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Output from your example dataset

```
id,disease_1,disease_2
1001,2008,2009
```

Comment: Yeah, if the question had all relevant info from the start (it still technically hasn't, it's just in comments), something simple like this would have been the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a simple CSV:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=min -F, -le 'print join ",", shift@F, map {min split /;/} @F' file.csv
id,disease_1,disease_2
1001,2008,2009
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say you prefer Python and SQL:

Write a Python script, which:

1. opens in the input CSV,
2. uses the `sqlite3` module to create an SQLite database, using the first line of the CSV to define the columns (probably all of type `INTEGER`?)
3. for each further line:

   1. splits each line by the commas,
   2. for each element yielded by that:

      1. splits by the semicolon
      2. takes the `min( int(value) for values in splitted )` or similar
      3. puts the resulting integer at the end of a list
   3. write the complete row list to the sqlite3 databse file
4. when done, saves the sqlite3 database file, and optionally, export it to CSV, should you **really** need the CSV format (you said you're happier with SQL, so get away from CSV as early as possible)

Now, having your data in a SQLite database file, you can run SQL queries against it – much nicer than handling CSV data. Also, you'll be delighted how much faster things like looking up things in the database will be. CSV is kind of a "worst case" database format: you need to always read all prior rows to find the Nth row; you always need read all prior columns to find the Mth column.

Answer (score 1):

With any awk and assuming sub-items are not already sorted in ascending order:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
function min(list) {
    subNums=split(list, numbr, /;/)
    min=numbr[1]
    for(n=2; n<=subNums; n++)
        if(numbr[n]<min)
            min=numbr[n]
    return min
}
{
  for(fldNr=2; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++)
      $fldNr=min($fldNr)
}' infile.csv
```

With GNU awk (for the [`asort()` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-asort_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029) to sort an array; also [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) option).

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc" }
{
  for(fldNr=2; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++)
  {
    subNums=split(fldNr, numArr, /;/)
    asort(numArr)
    $fldNr=numArr[1]
  }
}' infile.csv
```

- `BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }` sets the input and output field separator as ','.
- `subNums=split(fldNr, numArr, /;/)` splits the current field on `;` as the sub-delimiter and stores the resulting values in an array called *numArr*.
- then we used [`asort(numArr)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html) to sort the *numArr*'s values in ascending order.
- with `$fldNr=numArr[1]` we assign the first (minimum) value from the sorted *numArr* array to the current field#.

First awk command also do the same, but in there we iterate on the sub-numbers with a for-loop to find out the minimum by comparing each pair of numbers at a time without using of any GNU awk extensions.

However if your sub-numbers in each field is sorted in ascending order, then you only need to pick up the first one which is the minimum number, therfore the code will be much simpler.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
{
  for(fldNr=2; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++)
  {
    split($fldNr, numbr, /;/)
    $fldNr=numbr[1]
    continue
  }
}' infile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @data1 = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ",");
         @data1[1..*-1] = @data1[1..*-1]>>.split(";"); 
         @data1[1..*-1] = @data1[1..*-1]>>.map(*.min)>>.Array; 
         csv(in => @data1, out => $*OUT);'  < file
```

The Raku code above uses a *bona fide* CSV-parser, supplied by the `Text::CSV` module. Note, this answer simplifies the question a bit by assuming a single numeric value value in the *first* column. So after skipping the header row, the `min` can be taken for all row/columns, which saves on some sub-setting.

Briefly data is read into `@data1` array with the high-level `csv()` function. Elements within all rows except the first are split on `;` semicolon. Elements within all rows except the first are `map`ped to obtain the cell/field `min`imum.  Then data is output to `$*OUT` stdout with the high-level `csv()` function.

Sample Input:

```
id,disease_1,disease_2
1001,2008;2009,2009;2010
```

Sample Output:

```
id,disease_1,disease_2
1001,2008,2009
```

Note, both `$*IN` and `$*OUT` can be replaced with file-paths, reducing reliance on OS-supplied shell(s).

https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.md
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org